# BigCommerce - Add To Cart custom process

Tags: cart, bigcommerce

I'm newbie with BigCommerce.
I have to modify "add to Cart" process. Please see my diagram at below.
I just want check if it's possible to do that? And Where I can start my code?

[image]

Comment: this diagram is not helpful to understand the process you should be explained the bit more, also where is the customer's role here you just describe the only client.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj : I want to mean : when user/customer click to add an item to Cart, instead of item will be added directly, I want to have an another  custom page like : choose Size, Color of item ... and after that, custom item will be added to Cart

Comment: yes that is good lets think about it answer will update soon

Comment: Could possibly do something with an ajax call based off of clicking a "customize" button and then use https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/stencil-utils-api-reference#Cart-API